# Pandas rolling groupby with one group

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I am doing `groupby` and `rolling` to a `dataframe`.

If I have more than 1 group, the result is a `pandas series` but if I only have 1 group then the result is a `pandas dataframe`. I replicated it below if you need to see what I am doing.

**Is there a way to force pandas to return a series each time, even if there is only one group?**

If you wish to recreate what I am seeing, you can run the below examples.

**Example 1 (Series):**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill'],'Score':[1,1, 1,2,2, 2, 2]})
df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False)['Score'].rolling(2,min_periods=0).sum()
```

**Example 2 (Dataframe):**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Name':['John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John', 'John'],'Score':[1,1, 1,2,2, 2, 2]})
df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False)['Score'].rolling(2,min_periods=0).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

Series:

```
pd.Series(df.groupby('Name', as_index=False, sort=False)['Score'].rolling(2,min_periods=0).sum().values)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.